# Google Places API issue In TexSearch request

Tags: android, google-places-api

I am using  [google places API](https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/search#TextSearchRequests), in my android application and having some issue in it.

I just read document and implement TextSearch API. My problem is when I search for a place with passing current geo location and radius with "textsearch" request API always returns Places with same name but larger distance  but I want only places that are within provided radius.

Below is my request url -

> `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=search_token&key=MYAPIKEY&radius=50&location=22.7286293,75.8862315`

you can check response [here](http://justpaste.it/kuod).

According to API it should returns places that falls within my radius range that is 50 meters.

Is I am doing anything wrong  or miss understanding the API.

Please help me.
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

It is stated in the documentation that outside places may be included:

> Defines the distance (in meters) within which to bias place results. The maximum allowed radius is 50 000 meters. Results inside of this region will be ranked higher than results outside of the search circle; however, prominent results from outside of the search radius may be included.

If you want to filter out the results outside of the search radius you can still check if it falls in your radius by calling `Location.distanceBetween()`. See the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween(double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float[]))